# firebreath variables in custom file

Tags: firebreath

I have a firebreath plugin with installer.cmake script for Mac. Instead of creating a dmg file it creates a package based on pmdoc folder.

```
COMMAND ${CMD_CP} -r ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Mac/MyPlugin.pmdoc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/MyPlugin.pmdoc
COMMAND /Applications/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageMaker --doc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/MyPlugin.pmdoc --version ${FBSTRING_PLUGIN_VERSION} --out ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/MyPlugin.pkg
```

Problem is I want to use FB variables in one of the pmdoc file, for example set title to `${FBSTRING_PluginName} ${FBSTRING_PLUGIN_VERSION}` Obviously, copy command just copies the file, but how can I replace variables with their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cmake's [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html).  This will take an input file and an output file; the output file will have all variables replaced. Lots of examples of this in the firebreath codebase.

Comment: well, not a lot, only two files have this call, but I got the idea, thanks :)

Comment: FireBreath has its own version of this that is (in some ways) a bit more powerful called configure_template -- I guess all the other places use that.  It has advantages and disadvantages, though, and I think configure_file is more what you need.